# How to add a class without access to HTML

Tags: javascript

I want to add an additional class to an input. I have no access to the HTML to change the code.

I tried the below. I don't really know JS, but have to get this done for work.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function changeClass(){
        document.getElementById("en__field_supporter_emailAddress").className += " xverify_email";
    }

    window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementsByTagName("button").addEventListener( 'click', changeClass);
    }
</script>
```

I want the JS to insert the "xverify_email" class into the email address input line (which has the id en__field_supporter_emailAddress and also already has a class that must remain there) so that it can call the subsequent xverify JS to work.

Comment: so what is not working? Did you debug to see where it fails? `console.log()` is helpful.

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, not a single element. After calling that function you should access some specific index(es) of that returned collection.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10693845/what-do-queryselectorall-and-getelementsby-methods-return

Comment: I think you should debug your code.

Comment: The console says this: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementsByTagName(...).addEventListener is not a function
    at window.onload

Comment: Well, you have the answer `(:`

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you have a set of buttons, so you want to bind the event `click` to every button in the page:

```
Array.from(document.querySelectorALl('button')).forEach(function(btn) {
    btn.addEventListener('click', changeClass);
});
```

I recommend you to embrace the attribute `classList`:

```
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("en__field_supporter_emailAddress").classList.add("xverify_email");
}
```